# java string replace all

Tags: java, string, replace

I have a two dimensional array that contains pairs of strings. If one string is found it should replace it with its pair.

The code:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
        if (name.contains(pairs[i][0])) {
            name.replaceAll(pairs[i][0], abbr[i][1]);
        }
    }
```

It is not replacing the strings. What is the error?

Comment: Some sample input & expected output may help. As well as "review" it is case for replace() (or) replaceAll()? and last but not least, Strings are immutable.

Comment: Replace `abbr[i][1]` with `pairs[i][1]`...Also, use a `Map<String,String>` instead of bidimentional array...

Comment: I don't really get the question... Could you post the contents of the array BEFORE you run your code, and  the desired contents of the array AFTER you run your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are neglecting to assign the result of `replaceAll`, and so the modification is lost.

Perhaps you want to keep the modified string as `name`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
    if (name.contains(pairs[i][0])) {
        name = name.replaceAll(pairs[i][0], abbr[i][1]);
    }
}
```

Note that java `String` objects are immutable, so calling `name.replaceAll` *doesn't* modify `name`, it returns a *new* `String` with the modifications.

Answer (score 2):

String is immutable.

```
name.replaceAll(pairs[i][0], abbr[i][1]);
```

creates a new String (it doesn't modify the "name" String)

Try

```
name = name.replaceAll(pairs[i][0], abbr[i][1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

A modified version of the string is being created, however it's return value is being lost.

name = name.replaceAll(pairs[i][0], abbr[i][1]);

should work.

Comment: I don't think the string is being modified. A new one is created with the modification and being passed back.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize I had written it that way! Edited my answer.